# Java instance memory usage going up without requests

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-trace

I have a strange problem with GAE Java. There are two instances with basic scaling for the version I am using, with one being used and the other idling, from what I can see in the log. Response times are fine. I can see that my idle instance did not receive any requests for the last hour. Strangely, on the idle instance the memory usage goes up constantly at around a 2MB/minute. For the last hour. The instance is using a google JDBC connection to a mysql cloud sql instance. I am using a DBCP 1.4 connection pool with 2 connections, but I don't think there would be any active processing being done, as a background thread should not even be possible on appengine.
It is on ca. 730MB for a B2 instance (256MB?) and will probably get restarted soon because of memory usage.

I am also using tracing on the connection (com.google.cloud.trace.instrumentation.jdbc 0.1.1) but again I dont think this will do anything as long as there are not queries.

How could this happen? And how could I find the memory leak? I think normally threads would be stopped after 30s. And the JDBC driver from google should not be somehow filling up memory by itself I would guess.

Comment: What happens without the tracing instrumentation enabled? You may well have found a bug in instrumentation.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? If yes, could you clarify whether you are using Second generation Cloud SQL instance?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: It seems like its not related to JDBC at all. It seems to be a problem of the endpoint service control APIs:

[Cloud endpoint management leaking memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439225/cloud-endpoint-management-leaking-memory)

Comment: If you require further technical support in other issues, it is recommended to post your full detailed questions (as explained here ([ask]) in another post using the supported Cloud tags. Otherwise, your answers might be deleted in the thread, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: You are right, I created two new questions related to the problem